# How to convert Atmel ATmega328P instruction set code to burnable hex code

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega

I am about to start working on a project for which ATmega328P seems a good option. However I was trying to program it using its instruction set rather than using AVR's C library. This posed a problem of converting and burning the program to Atmega's flash memory. How can this be done?

Comment: assembly and C are no different.  C is compiled into asm then asm is made into an object then the object or objects are linked then you get the binary that is eventually loaded into the flash.  By using assembly you simply save one step, otherwise it is no different. github.com/dwelch67 avr_samples or avriss one of those or both should have asm and C build examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, that you have your code in AVR assembly language.
If so, you need avr-assembler. On linux systems this program is called avr-as and it's a part of avr-binutils package.
On windows machine I recommend installing "winavr" suite - it has same tools and even some eye candy IDE to ease some processes.

Once you have this covered, run your assembler on your code.

```
avr-as -mmcu=atmega328p  o my_program.elf my_code.asm
```

If everything builds cleanly, you will still need to convert the output into .hex format.
This can be done using avr-objcopy (from the same packages).

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex my_program.elf my_program.hex
```

After this you should have my_program.hex ready to be programmed into your controller.